# Toolbar/ActionConfiguration behavior difference between iPhone and Android

Tags: android, ios, tabris

The Action configuration behavior seems different between an iPhone and Android device.
On an iOS device,  the action items or buttons are permanently visible on a toolbar. On the Android the user has to select menu on their device first to make these action items visible in a list. The list will popup.

Is there are way to make these action items always visible on the Android, just like on the iPhone? Our customer base will for sure not know to press that button in order to see more options for our app.

Answer (score 1):

> On the Android the user has to select menu on their device first to make these action items visible in a list

It depends on the phone. This behavior is right only for the phones that have a menu button (like the Samsung ones). For the phones without a menu bouton (like the nexus 5 for example), menu can be visible after clicking on the "3 points" in the action bar (the number 3 is the following photo) :

[image]

> Is there are way to make these action items always visible on the Android, just like on the iPhone?

Yes ! If you see the number 2 into the previous photo, you can see that 2 icons are always visible (the glass and the google play store icon). These 2 icons are 2 menu items but setting as "show always".

More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Comment: @vraaijmakers : if you are satisfy by my answer please accept it :)